# How to implement text auto-completion of commands using dbgeng.h?

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

I am working on a front end for windbg which uses the pretty well documented `dbgeng.h` API. However there is some functionality that I don't know how to implement, such as tab auto-completion. I believe what I need are the following APIs:
[IDebugAdvanced3::Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugadvanced3-request)

[DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/ns-dbgeng-_debug_get_text_completions_out)

[DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/ns-dbgeng-_debug_get_text_completions_in)

DEBUG_REQUEST_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_ANSI (undocumented)

There are also some comments inside `dbgeng.h` where these structs are defined:

```
typedef struct _DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN
{
    ULONG Flags;
    ULONG MatchCountLimit;
    ULONG64 Reserved[3];
    // Input text string follows.
} DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN, *PDEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN;
```

```
typedef struct _DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT
{
    ULONG Flags;
    // Char index in input string where completions start.
    ULONG ReplaceIndex;
    ULONG MatchCount;
    ULONG Reserved1;
    ULONG64 Reserved2[2];
    // Completions follow.
    // Completion data is zero-terminated strings ended
    // by a final zero double-terminator.
} DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT, *PDEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT;
```

I don't understand how I'm supposed to use this API.

edit: I tried the following as suggested in the comments:

```
struct in_wrap
{
    DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN in;
    char src[4];
};
in_wrap wrp;

DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN in;
in.Flags = DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_NO_SYMBOLS;
in.MatchCountLimit = 5;

wrp.in = in;
strcpy(wrp.src, ".ec"); // I'm expecting to receive ".echo" back.

DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT out = {};
ULONG outsize = 0;

hr = advanced->Request(DEBUG_REQUEST_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_ANSI,
                      (void *)&wrp, sizeof(in_wrap),
                      (void *)&out, sizeof(DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT), &outsize);
```

Which returns `E_INVALIDARGS`.

Comment: I can't provide much help here, other than translating the source comments: It reads like the `_IN` and `_OUT` structures only carry part of the data. Either one is to be immediately followed by a list of strings, [terminated by an empty string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443). What's awkward is that structures following this pattern commonly [end with an array of size 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043). I cannot infer who is responsible for allocating or releasing those blocks of memory, though.

Comment: Typedef struct _FOO { debugin blah; char bar[somesize]}foo,*pfoo;  foo inbuff; strcpy_s (inbuff.bar,".dot/bang partial input");   Request get inbuff sizeof foo.............
Out completion memory is dbgengs work

Comment: @blabb I just posted what you suggested but unfortunately it still doesnt work. Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: The list of strings needs to be terminated by an empty string. In other words, the final 2 characters need to be NUL characters. You'll probably also want to populate (or at least initialize) the other members of the struct.

Comment: I added an answer take a look

Comment: @blabb Thank you so much! How did you figure out that you have to add an asterisk after your input string?

Comment: debug the debugger with .dbgdbg   set bp yourextensionname!Extension::yourextensionCommand  in code below it would be autocomp!Extension::autocomp and step around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the partial input is a wildcard so you need an asterisk following your input like ".db*"
2. the out needs two iterations one for getting the size with S_FALSE and size of completions available
   the second with allocated memory after OUT as a typedeffed structure as IN

the code below has a fixed size buffer in OUT as poc
if you pass just OUT without a buffer you should Receive an S_FALSE(01) as HRESULT

the opsize must indicate the amount of memorysize needed for completion characters

code as follows

```
#include <engextcpp.cpp>
typedef struct _AUTOCOMPIN {
    DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_IN auin;
    char instr[8];
} Autocompin, *PAutocompin;
typedef struct _AUTOCOMPOUT {
    DEBUG_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_OUT auout;
    char ostr[0x1000];
} Autocompout, *Pautocompout;
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension    {
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(autocomp);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(autocomp, "", "")    {
    Autocompin ibuff = {0};
    Autocompout obuff = {0};
    ULONG opsize = 0;
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    strcpy_s(ibuff.instr, ".d*");
    hr = m_Advanced2->Request(
        DEBUG_REQUEST_GET_TEXT_COMPLETIONS_ANSI,
        &ibuff,
        sizeof(ibuff),
        &obuff,
        sizeof(obuff),
        &opsize);
    Out("hr = %x opsize = %x IDebugAdvancedCheckPointer = %p\n", hr, opsize, m_Advanced2);
    for (ULONG i = 0; i < opsize; i++) {
        Out("%c ", obuff.ostr[i]);
    }
}
```

compiled and linked with

```
:\>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27045 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

:\>type complink.bat (must be in one line )
cl /LD /nologo /W4 /Od  /Zi /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc" %1.cpp   
/link /EXPORT:DebugExtensionInitialize /Export:%1 /Export:help /RELEASE
:\>
```

compiled and executed

```
:\>complink.bat autocomp

:\>cl /LD /nologo /W4 /Od  /Zi /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc" autocomp.cpp /link /EXPORT:DebugExtensionInitialize /Export:autocomp /Export:help /RELEASE
autocomp.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc\engextcpp.cpp(1849): warning C4245: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'ULONG64', signed/unsigned mismatch
   Creating library autocomp.lib and object autocomp.exp

:\>cdb -c ".load .\autocomp;!autocomp;q" cdb

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.load .\autocomp;!autocomp;q'
hr = 0 opsize = 8c IDebugAdvancedCheckPointer = 00000057edfface0
d b g d b g  
d e b u g _ s w _ w o w  
d e t a c h  
d m l _ f i l e  
d m l _ f l o w  
d m l _ s t a r t  
d o  d r i v e r s  
d u m p  
d v a l l o c  
d v f r e e  
d i s a b l e p a c k a g e d e b u g                                    
quit:
```